# How to Bind Checked / Selected Items From CheckListBox in WPF by using MVVM Model (I am using "WPFToolkit.Extended.dll" to get CheckListBox Control)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, checklistbox

CheckList Box from WPFToolKit. Below is XAML code **(MainWindow.xaml)**

```
<xctk:CheckListBox x:Name="SiteCheckList" Margin="0,0,512,0" Height="100" Width="150"
                               ItemsSource="{Binding SiteList}"
                               DisplayMemberPath="SiteName"
                               CheckedMemberPath="IsChecked">
            </xctk:CheckListBox>
```

Below Properties added in Model Class. I would like to get Checked Items from CheckListBox to my string List **(Model.cs)**.
This string List I will be using for further in project logic.

```
private string _SiteName;

        public string SiteName
        {
            get { return _SiteName; }
            set { _SiteName = value; }
        }

    private List<string> _SelectedSiteList;
            public List<string> SelectedSiteList
            {
                get { return _SelectedSiteList; }
                set
                {
                    _SelectedSiteList = value;
                }
            }
```

**View Model** (ViewModel.cs)

class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

```
    private ObservableCollection<Model> _SiteList;

    public ObservableCollection<DataModel> SiteList
    {
        get { return _SiteList; }
        set { _SiteList = value; }
    }

    public ViewModel()
    {
        SiteList = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
        PoppulateSiteNames();
    }


    private void PoppulateSiteNames()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        keyValuePairs = Files.ReadIni_KeyValue("SiteSection");
        foreach (string Key in keyValuePairs.Keys)
        {
            keyValuePairs.TryGetValue(Key, out string LogTable);
            SiteList.Add(new Model() { SiteName = LogTable });
        }

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged !=null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }

}
```

Here I would like to get list of Checked / Selected Items from UI. If I don't want to write any code in MainWindow.cs i.e. CheckedChanged event then How I can do it by using Binding method ?

Comment: Judging from the documentation about CheckListBox, all the selected items are in the SelectedItems collection.
If you need to process this list, then bind the command parameter to this property.
Also, if the collection element has a property for specifying the selected parameter, then you can specify it in the SelectedMemberPath.

Comment: How I can trigger once there is change in checklistbox. i.e. Item Check change ? In Short How to bind Command property ?

Comment: What do you need to do from where to what?

Comment: From your explanations, it is not clear which method, by which command, should get this list.
There is also no DataModel type code.
Does it have a property to indicate the selected item?
The `SiteList` collection-property shown in your code will not compile either, since the collection type of the `_SiteList` field is different.
Complete your question and show the WORKING code relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated **Model Class** with **IsChecked** Boolean Property.

```
private bool _IsChecked;

        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get { return _IsChecked; }
            set { _IsChecked = value; }
        }
```

Then **ViewModel** Updated with Below Function to Populate **SiteList**

```
 private void PoppulateSiteNames()
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> keyValuePairs = Files.ReadIni_KeyValue(Vars.MSSQL_Section);
            string [] Sites = keyValuePairs.Values.ToArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < Sites.Length; i++)
            {
                SiteList.Add(new HistoricalDataModel { SiteName = Sites[i] });
            }
        }
```

Now, Finally I got **CheckedItems** in below Variable using **LINQ**

```
var checkedSites = from site in SiteList
                                where (site.IsChecked == true)
                                select new { site.SiteName };
```

Thank you all of you for responding my question and triggering me to think more.